# Make a div that go somewhat curved

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

This question have been asked a billion times I think, but just another case.

**How to make this with HTML / CSS (and, if no other option, JS - I'm thinking of canvas or SVG)** :

[image]

*Notes : the div should be able to contain a scrolling background image on the whole green part. And this should work on IE9+ and common mobile devices (default browser). Also, the space around the shape needs to stay transparent (no white element to create the rounded shape can be used)*

What's the better option ?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @Abhitalks I think we may have just accidentally diagnosed colorblindness. As for the green bit, I don't think there'll be a reliable way to reproduce this without at least Javascript. I suppose it depends on the browser support that's needed too?

Comment: i think you should use an image on upper side.

Comment: You need to use CSS masking property ! I haven't yet used it, but checkout this article. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I have not tried anything so far : I'm asking this to know what the options I have. And yes, sorry, the red part is the green part (corrected) :)

Comment: For browser support : IE9+ and default browser on common mobile devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607844/drawing-curved-lines-to-connect-elements-on-web-page

You can check out this with plain CSS

Comment: What about ovelaying a white PNG/SVG with the shape as transparent, and use pointer-event for click-through?

Comment: Or even a more elegant pseudo element covering the white bit on the left? (CSS only)

Comment: @Deepak `clip-path` is not quite supported on IE / Edge yet.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell something : I can't put white image around this shape, it needs to stay transparent.

Comment: @Devian I can't see anything in this question that I can use here.

Comment: @Deepak as CSS mask won't be compatible enough, SVG mask, in the article you gave could do the job. Just need to test it on IE9 before trying something.

Comment: Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5f7wsp6n/1/ ?

Comment: @Abhitalks thank you for that try : this is what I need, but I need the space around to stay transparent, not white.

Comment: SVG clip-path works on IE9, I'll try this way and post the result.

Comment: @enguerranws: This is with `clip-path`. doesn't work in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/xptycnkg/1/

Comment: @Abhitalks http://jsfiddle.net/xptycnkg/2/ This works on IE9, but needs some improvements

Comment: @enguerranws This is a way of bending things. So you could probably use this on a bigger scale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS Implementation**

You can create a border shape within a container and hide the unwanted parts. I have used view port sized units to be scalable. It can be further improved to your requirement by manipulating with the values.

```css
body {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
.container {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vh;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.curve {
  background: transparent;
  border: 20vh solid #7cc576;
  border-radius: 35%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateY(-20vh);
  width: 50vh;
}
.container-left-curved {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.container-right-curved {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-left-curved">
  <div class="curve">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container container-right-curved">
  <div class="curve">
  </div>
</div>
```

**SVG Implementation**

I saved your image and generated the optimized SVG code through Inkscape editor. This looks a lot better than a pure CSS solution.

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<svg height="300px" width="200px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 492 746.00001" fill="#000">

  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-119.71 -187.93)">
    <path id="path3349" d="m189.71 620.93c0-206.67-0.33548-311-1-311-0.55 0-1-2.25-1-5s-0.45-5-1-5-1-1.9984-1-4.441c0-2.4425-0.45-4.7191-1-5.059-0.55-0.33992-1-1.9415-1-3.559s-0.45-2.941-1-2.941-1-1.0984-1-2.441c0-1.3425-0.45-2.7191-1-3.059-0.55-0.33992-1-1.9415-1-3.559s-0.45-2.941-1-2.941-1-0.88631-1-1.9696-0.9-3.572-2-5.5304c-1.1-1.9585-2-4.2222-2-5.0304 0-0.80827-0.45-1.4696-1-1.4696s-1-0.9-1-2-0.45-2-1-2-1-0.9-1-2-0.45-2-1-2-1-0.9-1-2-0.45-2-1-2-1-0.9-1-2-0.45-2-1-2-1-0.59015-1-1.3114c0-0.72129-0.9-2.2775-2-3.4582s-2-2.7323-2-3.448-0.9-1.8633-2-2.5503c-1.1-0.68696-2-2.0459-2-3.0198 0-0.97393-0.9-2.4195-2-3.2123-1.1-0.79284-2.0021-1.9047-2.0046-2.4708-0.002-0.56608-1.3525-2.4673-3-4.225-1.6474-1.7577-3-3.5577-3.0056-4-0.006-0.44232-2.2557-3.1613-5-6.0422-2.7444-2.8809-4.9897-5.6545-4.9897-6.1636 0-0.50907-2.534-3.4395-5.6312-6.512l-5.6312-5.5864h207.31 207.31l11.311 11.25c6.2212 6.1875 11.317 11.7 11.325 12.25 0.007 0.55 1.788 2.8 3.9571 5s3.9659 4.7875 3.9929 5.75 0.52562 1.75 1.1081 1.75c0.58246 0 0.73793 0.51953 0.34549 1.1545-0.39555 0.64-0.27852 0.88566 0.2626 0.55123 0.98336-0.60775 4.3329 2.601 4.3329 4.1507 0 0.45847 0.9 1.6481 2 2.6436 1.1 0.99549 2 2.6402 2 3.655s0.45 1.845 1 1.845 1 0.59015 1 1.3114c0 0.72129 0.9 2.2775 2 3.4582s2 2.8406 2 3.6886c0 0.84799 0.45 1.5418 1 1.5418s1 0.9 1 2 0.45 2 1 2 1 0.9 1 2 0.45 2 1 2 1 0.9 1 2 0.47656 2 1.059 2c0.58246 0 0.81241 0.39901 0.51101 0.88669-0.30141 0.48768 0.12204 1.4428 0.94098 2.1224 0.81894 0.67966 1.489 2.0806 1.489 3.1133s0.45 1.8776 1 1.8776 1 1.35 1 3 0.45 3 1 3 1 1.1516 1 2.559c0 1.4514 0.43284 2.2915 1 1.941 0.58342-0.36057 1 0.65628 1 2.441 0 1.6825 0.45 3.059 1 3.059s1 1.8 1 4 0.45 4 1 4 1 1.8 1 4 0.45 4 1 4 1 2.25 1 5 0.45 5 1 5c0.66452 0 1 104 1 310v310h-210-210v-311z"
    fill="#7ac474" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: As said in comment above, I need the space around to stay transparent, but thank you for your effort.

Comment: @enguerranws I believe the author has changed the color from white to transparent.

Comment: @enguerranws It is transparent now. Check the body background applied.

Comment: Thank you really much. This is a solid example. The only thing is : after changing border-radius and translateY values,  I can't reproduce my example (left curve and right curve have never the same radius).

Comment: I have updated the snippet. Is that what you meant by left and right curve?

Comment: If you are changing the values of `border-radius` and `translateY`, you will also need to change the `width` and `height` values proportionally of the container and curve.

Comment: I still think svg is a much better way of doing this!

Comment: Still, the radius on the left and right sides are not the same (on Chrome/Mac).

Comment: @MozzieMD Agree! SVG seems simpler.

Comment: @Harry Thanks! :) Just a beginner in SVG. I was not sure if the other path elements are not correlated with the entire output.

Comment: @ManojKumar: This is much better :) SVG is awesome and you will not regret getting in. By the way, feel free to join me and few other users active in the shapes tag [in this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs) when you find time.

Comment: Yes, as I thought, SVG is what I need. For extended compatibility and manipulation, I used RaphaelJS to make it.

Answer (score 1):

*Finally, after looking for the good way to achieve that, here's my notes:*

**1. RaphaelJS**

**I think RaphaelJS makes it easy and offers extended compatibility** (I tested on IE8 and IE7, it works, even if I don't need it) **and easier manipulation**.

Here's a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/bkfssykp/

As you can see, this is somewhat a SVG based solution :

```
paper.path("M0,0h259.478c0,0,42.939,36.419,42.939,88.694    c0,132.905,0,368.306,0,368.306H42.939c0,0,0-235.587,0-368.464C42.939,36.345,0,0,0,0z");
```

*I just pasted the code of my svg shape directly into it*. Now, I can play with it : animation, modification, etc.

**2. SVG clip-path**

My first attempt was an SVG image with a SVG clip-path, as said in the article mentionned by @Deepak : https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Here's a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/xptycnkg/3/

Still SVG : this looks like CSS clip-path, but applied on SVG  element. Works on IE9.